# translating LOOKUP from VBA into excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

i have a formula that looks like this in VBA:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(""ETG_C"",RC[-10],RC[-8])"
```

what would be the exact equivalent of this if i simply input it into the worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely have "normal" cell references like "A1" instead of less common relative reference "RC[-10]" (which means 10 columns to the left on the current row)

So it would look something like:

```
=LOOKUP("ETG_C",B1,D1)
```

or whatever the correct cells were.

Edit: If you want to keep the relative reference style, then all that would change would be the double quotes:

```
=LOOKUP("ETG_C",RC[-10],RC[-8])
```

Comment: i dont want to do it implicitly, i want to keep the -10 and -8 syntax thanks!